# Javamelody, spring boot management port and jetty

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, java-melody

For security purposes, I'd like to have javamelody running on my app management port, not the main traffic port. This is a 1.5.13 spring boot app running jetty with some actuator endpoints enabled. I have set the actuator property `management.port` to something other than the `server.port`.

I can run javamdelody in a standalone jetty server on a third port using an approach like [this github project](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/blob/master/javamelody-for-standalone/src/main/java/net/bull/javamelody/EmbeddedServer.java). But three ports is a little wieldy in a micro-service context.

This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145640/how-to-make-javamelody-use-different-port-spring-boottwo-http-ports-exposed) has answers for Tomcat, but not for Jetty. Any suggestions to run javamelody on the management port with Jetty?